# docker build was failed due to "COPY failed: no such file or directory" error

Tags: reactjs, docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, travis-ci

I'm setting up travis-ci to build & push docker images when they are committed to github.
But client docker image is not built & pushed to docker hub even though api & nginx images are succeeded.

Sorce code is here:
https://github.com/jpskgc/article

- client: react
- api: golang
- ci: travis-ci

This is `.travis.yml`

```
language: generic
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t jpskgc/react-test -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client

script:
  - docker run -e CI=true jpskgc/react-test npm test

after_success:
  - docker build -t jpskgc/multi-client ./client
  - docker build -t jpskgc/multi-nginx ./nginx
  - docker build -t jpskgc/multi-api ./api
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
  - docker push jpskgc/multi-client
  - docker push jpskgc/multi-nginx
  - docker push jpskgc/multi-api
```

this is `Dockerfile` in client.

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I expect client docker image is build & pushed to dockerhub.
But the actual is not created.

```
4.75s$ docker build -t [secure]/multi-client:latest ./client
553Sending build context to Docker daemon   1.22MB
554Step 1/10 : FROM node:alpine as builder
555 ---> d97a436daee9
556Step 2/10 : WORKDIR '/app'
557 ---> Using cache
558 ---> 9f51c260f236
559Step 3/10 : COPY ./package.json ./
560 ---> Using cache
561 ---> e46d1f93865a
562Step 4/10 : RUN npm install
563 ---> Using cache
564 ---> 4961700b8f5c
565Step 5/10 : COPY . .
566 ---> Using cache
567 ---> 4a5333f50509
568Step 6/10 : CMD npm run build
569 ---> Running in 15030b24cd9a
570 ---> e967a522abbe
571Removing intermediate container 15030b24cd9a
572Step 7/10 : FROM nginx
573latest: Pulling from library/nginx
574f5d23c7fed46: Pulling fs layer
575918b255d86e5: Pulling fs layer
5768c0120a6f561: Pulling fs layer
5778c0120a6f561: Download complete
578918b255d86e5: Verifying Checksum
579918b255d86e5: Download complete
580f5d23c7fed46: Download complete
581f5d23c7fed46: Pull complete
582918b255d86e5: Pull complete
5838c0120a6f561: Pull complete
584Digest: sha256:eb3320e2f9ca409b7c0aa71aea3cf7ce7d018f03a372564dbdb023646958770b
585Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
586 ---> e445ab08b2be
587Step 8/10 : EXPOSE 3000
588 ---> Running in 84d04cfc54e6
589 ---> 1ed6838be8e8
590Removing intermediate container 84d04cfc54e6
591Step 9/10 : COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
592 ---> eb7dd4d2b5a6
593Step 10/10 : COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
594COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8eab810f807b8244ed20da7b916d08aa7dc2baf99237b8ecba323e39d0a71cea/merged/app/build: no such file or directory
after_success.2
5950.20s$ docker build -t [secure]/multi-nginx ./nginx
after_success.3
60367.74s$ docker build -t [secure]/multi-api ./api
after_success.4
6800.61s$ echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
after_success.5
6820.04s$ docker push [secure]/multi-client:latest
683The push refers to a repository [docker.io/[secure]/multi-client]
684An image does not exist locally with the tag: [secure]/multi-client
after_success.6
6853.94s$ docker push [secure]/multi-nginx
after_success.7
69626.63s$ docker push [secure]/multi-api
742
743Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

Comment: add `RUN ls -l `after `COPY . .` in your builder to see what `/app` contains

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create the build using `npm run build`. You put this into `CMD` which means it will run when you start a container from this image, but not at build time.

If you want to create the application build at image build time you need to run `npm run build` using `RUN` just as you do with `npm install`.

This version should work:

```sh
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If this doesn't work then please check what `npm run build` actually does in your application.

Comment: I have the similar configuration but still getting same error. The only difference is, i am using Angular and my build command in package.json file is "ng build --prod".Please help in this

Comment: @MANJITKUMAR The issue doesn't mention an error, only something that didn't happen. Also did you apply exactly the solution? Maybe it would help to open a new question with your configuration files and I can look at it.

Comment: I found the solution the issue is the path of angular(/app/dist/{app-name}) is different than React app('/app/build/'), after correcting path it worked fine